# Incrementing register past its limits. Assembly language addition

Tags: assembly, binary, x86, increment, cpu-registers

What will be the value in EAX after the following lines execute?

```
mov    eax, 1002FFFFh
inc    ax
```

The answer is `1002000h`.

My question is, why is the answer not `1003 0000h`, or `1002 0000h` considering that we initially start with something that is 32 bits, and the answer is somehow 32-4 bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're increasing AX, which is 16 bit, and overflows to 0x0000
so the answer is 0x10020000 (not 0x1002000 as you stated, probably a typo)

to have 0x10030000 as result you'd have to increase EAX instead

Comment: Where can I find out further information about this syntax: '0x0000' , is this some sort of hexadecimal exclusive syntax? Does an OF flag go off in this case?

Comment: oh sorry for the confusion, that's C style for hexadecimal :-) `0x10030000` means what you'd used `10030000h` for

Comment: @SajSeesSound: NASM and GNU assemblers support `0xDEADBEEF` style constants like C, as well as the MASM-style `0DEADBEEFh`.  Windows-only assemblers usually only support the annoying `...h` style.